# Pandas: transpose doesn't transpose rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in a csv with the following code:

```
df=pd.read_csv(file, index_col="Votes")
```

Which gives this result:

```
votes  10  20  5  30
  1st   a   e  b   c
  2nd   b   a  c   e
```

I want to transpose this to look like the following:

```
votes  1st  2nd 
   10    a    b
   20    e    a
    5    b    c
   30    c    e
```

And I want `votes`, `1st`, `2nd` to be columns. But transposing like this `df_t = df.T` keeps the columns as `10`, `20` etc.

How do I get the columns to be recognized as `votes`, `1st` etc?

If it helps, my proximate goal is to sum `votes` for each `a` in `1st`, etc. (ranked choice voting).

Comment: `df_t = df.T` or `df_t = df.tranpose()` both work for me to get your expected output.

What exactly are you getting as your output? And are you calling `df_t` or just the original `df` to get your wrong-looking output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your DataFrame :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
votes,10,20,5,30
1st,a,e,b,c
2nd,b,a,c,e
"""), sep=',', index_col="votes")
>>> df
       10   20  5   30
votes               
1st    a    e   b   c
2nd    b    a   c   e
```

We can indeed use `T` to transpose it as expected :

```py
>>> df_T = df.T
>>> df_T
votes   1st 2nd
10      a   b
20      e   a
5       b   c
30      c   e
```

Then, as asked in the commentary section, we can setup the index like so :

```py
>>> df_T['votes'] = df_T.index
>>> df_T = df_T.reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df_T.columns.name = None
>>> df_T
    1st 2nd votes
0   a   b   10
1   e   a   20
2   b   c   5
3   c   e   30
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, visually, but the index remains as the colums and when I try to change the index `df.index = pd.Index(range.(...), name='idx')` it won't let me because of the shape mismatch assuming it must be length of cols instead of rows.

Comment: Hi @extDependency, I just updated the answer to add the change in the `index`. Happy to help  !